# Android. WindowBackground center icon not centered like Activity icon

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layer-list acting as my splashscreen's window background

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_logo_splash"
        android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

And I set it to styles like so and add the theme to the `Activity` inside the manifest.

```
<style name="BackgroundedSplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bckgnd</item>
</style>
```

I also have an `Activity` which has a simple layout which contains, among 2 other things, the `ic_logo_slash` that I set in the above `layer-list`. It's contained inside a `LinearLayout` with

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_splash"/>
```

so nothing special.

My **PROBLEM** is that you can first see the `layer-list` with the logo, after 1 second the splashscreen activity gets displayed (everything ok until now) but the issue is that the logo set as the `windowBackground` is **lower** than the logo in the splashscreen. It would seem that the `Activity` layout is a bit larger than ... what ?! the actual window ?! I'm very confused where the extra top padding comes for the window and why is the icon a bit lower than the one in the Activity. They're both centered, so they should be in the same position, no? The window and the activity layout have the same size ... no ? their centers should thus be the same center...

Left is the activity's layout, right is the layer-layout (so the window's background). When the activity's layout is eventually displayed, you can see the logo move up a bit, it looks really bad

[image]

Help ?!

**EDIT**

I played around with it and it seems to be a `24dp` difference between the two. 'wonder where it comes from.

Answer (score 4):

I've been trying to deal with this problem myself. And I think I have a solution.

The problem is that windowBackground in a theme has a larger area that it's working with (the window) compared to the area that your activity uses. The window also includes system bars and whatnot.

Your splash theme is centering its image in the window. Your activity is centering its image in the activity. These aren't necessarily the same.

I spent a long time trying to find a reliable solution, and the best I could find was a custom view that manually calculates the center of the window and draws the image there.

I think this is better than other solutions I've seen which seem to rely on having an Activity dedicated to being the splash screen so they can use `background` instead of `windowBackground` in the theme, or aren't reliable enough (they didn't work for me anyway).

First you need to put this in your res/values/attrs.xml:

```
    <declare-styleable name="WindowCenteredImageView">
        <!-- Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView. -->
        <attr name="src" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

Now replace your ImageView with this:

```
<your.package.name.WindowCenteredImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:src="@drawable/ic_logo_splash"/>
```

And here's the code for that new class:

```
package your.package.name

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Point
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import your.package.name.R

/**
 * Simply draws the given drawable in the center of the current window with no scaling. This is not
 * very sophisticated, so cannot handle a lot of the features that a regular [ImageView] can. If
 * these features are required, you might want to try subclassing [ImageView].
 */
class WindowCenteredImageView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): View(context, attrs) {

    // Obtain drawable from attributes.
    private val d: Drawable?
    init {
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.WindowCenteredImageView,
            0, 0
        ).apply {
            try {
                d = getDrawable(R.styleable.WindowCenteredImageView_src)
            } finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        if (d != null) {
            // We have a drawable, so try to draw it!
            if (d.intrinsicWidth >= 0 && d.intrinsicHeight >= 0) {
                // Our drawable doesn't fill the screen, so we should calculate its bounds. This is
                // where we take into account the current view's offset within the window...
                val viewTopLeftRelativeToWindow = onDrawCachedObjects.point1.apply {
                    val array = onDrawCachedObjects.array.apply { getLocationInWindow(this) }
                    set(array[0], array[1])
                }

                // And the window's dimensions...
                // (Casting here can't fail as views are always given activity context.)
                val window = (context as Activity).window.decorView
                val windowHeight = window.height
                val windowWidth = window.width

                // Do the calculations.
                // First, find out where we want the image to go in the window
                val imageTopLeftRelativeToWindow = onDrawCachedObjects.point2.apply {
                    set(
                        (windowWidth / 2) - (d.intrinsicWidth / 2),
                        (windowHeight / 2) - (d.intrinsicHeight / 2)
                    )
                }

                // Now we can calculate where the image should go in the view
                val imageTopLeftRelativeToView = onDrawCachedObjects.point3.apply {
                    set(
                        imageTopLeftRelativeToWindow.x - viewTopLeftRelativeToWindow.x,
                        imageTopLeftRelativeToWindow.y - viewTopLeftRelativeToWindow.y
                    )
                }

                // We have all the information needed to set the image bounds
                d.setBounds(
                    imageTopLeftRelativeToView.x,
                    imageTopLeftRelativeToView.y,
                    imageTopLeftRelativeToView.x + d.intrinsicWidth,
                    imageTopLeftRelativeToView.y + d.intrinsicHeight
                )
            }

            // Draw the drawable onto the canvas
            d.draw(canvas)
        }
    }

    /** Optimization: Objects to use in [onDraw] to avoid instantiations */
    private val onDrawCachedObjects = object {
        val array = IntArray(2)
        val point1 = Point()
        val point2 = Point()
        val point3 = Point()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only and best option as we can't adjust it just by padding and margin.